# Как найти второе слово JS?

Tags: javascript

Как найти второе слово всех `<h3>` через javascript?

```html
<h3>Заголовок один</h3>
<h3>Заголовок два</h3>
<h3>Заголовок три</h3>
<h3>Заголовок четыре</h3>
<h3>Заголовок пять</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const secondWords = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('h3'),
  h => h.innerText.split(' ')[1],
);

console.log(secondWords);
```

```html
<h3>Заголовок один</h3>
<h3>Заголовок два</h3>
<h3>Заголовок три</h3>
<h3>Заголовок четыре</h3>
<h3>Заголовок пять</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let index = 0; // h3 item index
let word = document.querySelectorAll("h3")[index].innerText.split(" ")[1];
console.log(word);
```

```html
<h3>Заголовок один</h3>
<h3>Заголовок два</h3>
<h3>Заголовок три</h3>
<h3>Заголовок четыре</h3>
<h3>Заголовок пять</h3>
```